# Getting SLL certification information on Android webview

Tags: android, ssl, https, webview, certificate

I am using webview in my app. when the user browses to a https site, how do I get the certificate information for the site/page that just finished loading.

Just like how when you click on the green lock icon on chrome browser and it pops up a dialog with certificate information, how do I get it from webview?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, dont know how I missed this!!!!

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
{
    Log.e(view.getCertificate().toString());
}
```